# Can't seem to understand what HW is asking for C++ class

Tags: c++

> You cannot evaluate any value or expression for truth or falsity because it is determined by the keywords true and false.
>
> A.True
> B.False

At first, i picked true but then i thought maybe it is false since anything can be assigned to true or false but i still am unsure of what it is asking.

Comment: You understand what **evaluate** for truth or falsity means?

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand what it wants either.

Comment: I believe so isn't it just to test if to see if we get back 0 for a statement (false) or any non zero number (true)

Comment: @PhantomXman - So you know what it means. Now, what is an expression?

Comment: Yea i am lost in what it is asking and sadly my instructor basically refuse to help until after we finish the assignment

Comment: @melpomene - Thought you were addressing me. Got notified and everything. Well done SO.

Comment: Just go with **false** answer. Expressions and values **can** be used in conditionals and evaluated to either `0` which is `false` or something other than `0` which translates to `true`.

Comment: @PhantomXman - Your instructor is refusing because they probably covered it in the course material.

Comment: Specific issues: It's unclear whether they mean "there is no expression E such that E can be evaluated for truth/falseness" or "there exists an expression E such that  E cannot be evaluated for truth/falseness". Even if you pick one of those interpretations, there's the second half: "... because it is determined by the keywords true and false". What is that even supposed to mean? I've got nothing.

Comment: No he didn't its an online course I'm basically teaching myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is: B. False. You **can** evaluate values and expressions to something else other than `true` or `false`. The expression is **not** "*determined by the keywords true and false*" which are simply [boolean literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bool_literal). The expression can be of:

> integral, floating-point, unscoped enumeration, pointer, and
>   pointer-to-member types

And can be converted to a value of `bool` by means of [boolean conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Boolean_conversions).
I think this question can be roughly translated to:
"Must values and expressions in conditions be of type [bool](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Boolean_type)?". And the answer is **no**.

Comment: This is possibly the right interpretation, but the homework question is so vague/poor that it's anyone's guess as to whether this is what the teacher meant.